# c# convert string to table ( for easier using table, like command)

Tags: c#, command

Is any c# lib which convert string like linux command?
example:

```
myCommand -t 123 -s string -ff "string string string"
```

give me output like

```
["myCommand"]=>{
  ["t"]=123,
  ["s"]="string",
  ["ff"]="string string string"
}
```

and example how use :)

Comment: you can write your batch.

Comment: Use/search for lib to do such simple string parsing is pretty sad.